# Control redirect from a html file and not in Nginx configs

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I've got a case where I need to setup a nginx server that only will serve sites (about 800) with static content.  Many of the sites will initially have no real content themselves and should just be redirected to a "master" domain.  Like foo.my foo.net will initially be 301 redirected to foo.com, but will at a later stage be sites with their own content.

I need to figure out a way to let the webmaster be able to control the redirection himself without having to edit the nginx config files.

With php on the server it'd be really easy, but now?  It seems like SSI can't modify the headers, there are no .htaccess files in nginx what could hold the redirect.

So is there a way to do a redirect from a html file? Or is it possible to in the config test if a particular file exists and then use the contents of that file as the target for a rewrite? Or any other method to achieve this except for a butt-ugly 0-second meta-refresh that might be really bad SEO-wise?

Comment: How fixed are you on nginx? A [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) would suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do custom things with [embedded perl scripts](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) for example, and you can [call them from SSI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html#ssi).

You'll have to measure the performance impact of such thing if it can be run from 800 server blocks.

If it's noticeable, better [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) nginx subconfig files and teach your webmaster the syntax (in this case the config files will reside in memory).